# convert audio octet-stream to .wav in nodejs

Tags: node.js, wav

I currently receive a stream that is in binary format but with the help of nodej I want to convert that stream to .wav audio.

Currently I can get the audio in .raw and I can play it in audacity but I don't know how to convert it to .wav.

if anyone can help me, thanks.

Comment: For a light weight approach you can check the sources of Matt Diamonds `Recorder.js` implementation: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: _"I don't know how to convert it to .wav."_ A WAV file is just two pieces of data, first is the header bytes (which tells the media player about what samplerate etc to expect from incoming sound), then secondly join your raw audio after it, then it should play in any media player afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use *ffmpeg* it a great package to deal with audio and video.
there is a wrapper for nodejs, you could install it

> npm i fluent-ffmpeg

then you could execute your ffmpeg command from you nodejs application.
this should be helpful https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types to chose the right command to execute